# Eclipse - Shazamcrest - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NONE

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, hamcrest

I'm getting this error in Eclipse STS 3.6.3.  I have basic Hamcrest calls working after removing the hamcrest jar from the eclipse plugins dir.  From what I can tell, it's using hamcrest 1.3 and JUnit 4.  I looked in Run > Run Configurations > myTest > Source Tab > Defaults and I see the hamcrest 1.3 jar from my local maven repo.

It works using mvn command line, but not in eclipse.

Any idea what's going on here and how I can fix?

```
@Test
public void testShazamcrestMap() throws Exception {
    HashMap<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>(); 
    HashMap<String,String> item2 = new HashMap<String,String>();

    item.put("foo", "bar");
    item2.put("foo", "bar");

    assertThat(item, sameBeanAs(item2));
}
```

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NONE
>       at org.hamcrest.DiagnosingMatcher.matches(DiagnosingMatcher.java:12)
>       at com.shazam.shazamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:40)
>       at com.shazam.shazamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:29)
>       at com.nick.feed.test.SomeUnitTest.testShazamcrestMap(SomeUnitTest.java:49)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Comment: Leaving this open, but I was able to use org.unitils.reflectionassert.ReflectionAssert.assertReflectionEquals to accomplish a deep comparison of objects.  ...got it working in 20 mins after spending a considerable amount of time hacking with eclipse, hamcrest and shazamcrest.

Comment: `HashMap` includes a lot of internal fields that may trip up the reflection and/or JSON conversion of `sameBeanAs`. I would stick with Java Beans when using that matcher.

Comment: Ok, good advice. Sounds like shazamcrest converts to JSON first and then does the comparison, but there's probably reflection involved in the conversion if not elsewhere. As I said though, np with unitils.

Answer (score 2):

I ran this test successfully from from IntelliJ.

My environment: junit-4.12, hamcrest-1.3, shazamcrest-0.9

Ensure you only have one possible dependency for Hamcrest. Older versions of Junit are notorius for causing Hamcrest issues.

Junit 4.10 and prior actually has Hamcrest embedded (in addition to having a Maven dependency). If you must use Junit 4.10 or prior, use junit-dep which doesn't include Hamcrest. I would recommend updating to Junit 4.12

The version of Eclipse you are using might include Hamcrest via Junit as well. If that is the case, Google for removing it.